# Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug'

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, sos

I need help what is the problem i cant fix it i am so frustrated

```
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.2.RELEASE)

2019-12-09 22:02:13.914  INFO 10292 --- [           main] com.emavias.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication on Jürgen with PID 10292 (C:\emavias\demo\target\classes started by Jürgen in C:\emavias\demo)
2019-12-09 22:02:13.922  INFO 10292 --- [           main] com.emavias.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-12-09 22:02:15.706  INFO 10292 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-12-09 22:02:15.745  INFO 10292 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 30ms. Found 0 MongoDB repository interfaces.
2019-12-09 22:02:16.414  INFO 10292 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.hateoas.config.HateoasConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.hateoas.config.HateoasConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$852d2db8] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-12-09 22:02:16.449  INFO 10292 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'relProviderPluginRegistry' of type [org.springframework.plugin.core.support.PluginRegistryFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-12-09 22:02:16.455  INFO 10292 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'relProviderPluginRegistry' of type [org.springframework.plugin.core.OrderAwarePluginRegistry] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-12-09 22:02:16.459  INFO 10292 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean '_relProvider' of type [org.springframework.hateoas.server.core.DelegatingLinkRelationProvider] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-12-09 22:02:16.470  INFO 10292 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'messageResolver' of type [org.springframework.hateoas.mediatype.MessageSourceResolver] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-12-09 22:02:16.472  INFO 10292 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.hateoas.mediatype.hal.HalMediaTypeConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.hateoas.mediatype.hal.HalMediaTypeConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$df21bc8d] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-12-09 22:02:16.479  INFO 10292 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-12-09 22:02:16.482  INFO 10292 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-12-09 22:02:16.486  INFO 10292 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-12-09 22:02:16.522  INFO 10292 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'spring.jackson-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-12-09 22:02:16.527  INFO 10292 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'standardJacksonObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration$StandardJackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-12-09 22:02:16.533  INFO 10292 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$ParameterNamesModuleConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$ParameterNamesModuleConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-12-09 22:02:16.558  INFO 10292 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'parameterNamesModule' of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paramnames.ParameterNamesModule] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-12-09 22:02:16.561  INFO 10292 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-12-09 22:02:16.584  INFO 10292 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'jsonComponentModule' of type [org.springframework.boot.jackson.JsonComponentModule] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-12-09 22:02:16.587  INFO 10292 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataJacksonConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataJacksonConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-12-09 22:02:16.600  INFO 10292 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'jacksonGeoModule' of type [org.springframework.data.geo.GeoModule] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-12-09 22:02:16.605  INFO 10292 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' of type [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-12-09 22:02:16.675  INFO 10292 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'jacksonObjectMapper' of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-12-09 22:02:16.729  INFO 10292 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'hypermediaWebMvcConverters' of type [org.springframework.hateoas.config.WebConverters] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-12-09 22:02:17.326  INFO 10292 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9000 (http)
2019-12-09 22:02:17.347  INFO 10292 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-12-09 22:02:17.347  INFO 10292 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.29]
2019-12-09 22:02:17.590  INFO 10292 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-12-09 22:02:17.590  INFO 10292 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3528 ms
2019-12-09 22:02:19.008  INFO 10292 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-12-09 22:02:19.436  WARN 10292 --- [           main] ion$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
2019-12-09 22:02:19.877  WARN 10292 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: state should be: databaseName does not contain ' '
2019-12-09 22:02:19.879  INFO 10292 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-12-09 22:02:19.886  INFO 10292 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-12-09 22:02:19.912  INFO 10292 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-12-09 22:02:19.932 ERROR 10292 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: state should be: databaseName does not contain ' '
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.emavias.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: state should be: databaseName does not contain ' '
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: state should be: databaseName does not contain ' '
    at com.mongodb.assertions.Assertions.isTrueArgument(Assertions.java:99) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.MongoNamespace.checkDatabaseNameValidity(MongoNamespace.java:61) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.ConnectionString.<init>(ConnectionString.java:370) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.MongoClientURI.<init>(MongoClientURI.java:253) ~[mongodb-driver-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoClientFactory.createMongoClient(MongoClientFactory.java:108) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoClientFactory.createNetworkMongoClient(MongoClientFactory.java:91) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoClientFactory.createMongoClient(MongoClientFactory.java:67) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration.mongo(MongoAutoConfiguration.java:51) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Post your `application.properties`. There is something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: state should be: databaseName does not contain ' '
```

Means that you trying to create a data base name with white spaces in MongoDB.

MongoDB has some rules for DB names. The first of all is that database names is case insensitive this way names cannot differ only by the case of the characters. And database name cannot be empty and must have fewer than 64 characters.

If you are running you MongoDB in **Windows**, database names cannot contain any of the following characters including white spaces, or null charactere:

```
/\. "$*<>:|?
```

And if you are running you MongoDB in **Linux**, database names cannot contain any of the following characters including white spaces, or null charactere:

```
  /\. "$
```

for more information: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#namespaces